# ActiveMQ OpenWire: How can I send the Java custom fields of an Exception thrown in BrokerFilter.send to the client/producer JVM side?

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

In order to create the functionality of listening on the client (producer/consumer) side to custom Exceptions thrown in broker plugins we're trying to relay a "custom correlation id" created upon message send, attached as property to the message and also attached to a JVM structure together with the callback to be called upon that exception being raised (a listener).

The things works, but the only issue we have is that we cannot send that custom correlation id back as part of the exception - it is a custom field, and by default OpenWire only transmits the stack and the message, is that correct?

What possibilities do you suggest to work this out, and be able to transmit back custom fields/values (other than encoding them in the message)?

Comment: What is "a JVM structure"?

Comment: It would probably be best to share the client code and broker plugin code & configuration that you're using.